# Gain Perfomance of Postgresql Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure, ubuntu

I have a postgresql Database with a denormalized Schema (1 Table) with around 4 Million entries. Now i have this query:

```
SELECT
  count(*) AS Total,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM table
   WHERE "Timestamp" > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 hour' AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%') AS hour,

  (SELECT count(*) FROM table
   WHERE "Timestamp" > now() :: DATE AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%') AS day,

  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM table
   WHERE "Timestamp" > now() :: DATE - INTERVAL '1 day' AND
         "Timestamp" <= now() :: DATE - INTERVAL '1 day' AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%') AS yesterday,

  (SELECT count(*) FROM table
   WHERE "Timestamp" > now() :: DATE - INTERVAL '2 day' AND
         "Timestamp" <= now() :: DATE - INTERVAL '1 day' AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%') AS "dayBeforeYesterday",

  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM table WHERE "Timestamp" > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 week' AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%') AS week,

  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM table
   WHERE "Timetamp" > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '2 week' AND
        "Timestamp" < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 week' AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%') AS "lastWeek",

  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM table
   WHERE "Timestamp" > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '3 week' AND
        "Timestamp" < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '2 week' AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%') AS "weekBeforeLastWeek",

  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM table
   WHERE"Timestamp" > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 month' AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%')AS month

FROM table WHERE "tableName" LIKE '%ping%';
```

This takes around 14 Sec to 2 minutes (depends on how much other stuff is going on). but my server, which is a VM with ubuntu hosted on Azure always has both CPUs covered by 100%. 
If i check the statistics of postgesql, it's mostly this query, which blocks the whole CPU. 
It's a D2 VM with 2 Cores, 7gb SSD.
Is there a way to speed this up without upgrading my Azure Package?

Comment: Did you check the performance impact of the denormalisation? Given the fact that this query refers to only three columns, normalisation would definitely decrease the memory footprint of this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of all those sub-queries, use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  count(*) AS Total,
  count(case when "Timestamp" > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 hour' AND "tableName" LIKE '%ping%' then 1 end) AS hour,
...
```